# Authentication Issue: Multiple publish of a single web application on IIS7 with different ports

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, httpmodule

I have a ASP MVC2 web application and I want to publish multiple versions of it on my customers' IIS Server. Everything works just fine except that no one can log in to any two of the websites in a single browser at once. I thought this might be because of sessions conflict or something with HTTP module.

Any guide to how can I fix this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'no one can log in to any two of the websites in a single browser at once', what does the user see if he does try? also, are the 2 websites sharing the same host-name, only the port number changes?

Comment: There isn't any host name. just IP an yeah, the only difference is the port number. If a user log in to any, he will be automatically logged out from the other one.

Comment: Since you're accessing both websites using the same host-name (and the only difference is the port number), Cookies (hence probably Session as well) are shared between your sites. try to use different host-name for each site.